# Why I cannot browse github pages with .html suffix?

Tags: html, github

I just create a blog on github(lxuc.github.io). I create a directory "pages" and create 2 html files(category.html and archives.html) in it.

I use page.url to get these pages' url. The archives.html page url is lxuc.github.io/pages/archives/

But I cannot browse this page when I add .html suffix to this link like this:
lxuc.github.io/pages/archives.html.

I try to browser  lxuc.github.io/pages/index.html. It works fine.
Why?

Thank you very much.